# How to update page1 button's content from page2 in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone-8

I have two pages. 
**i)  HomePage** -- which **contains one button to display user selected city**(by defalut Delhi)
**ii) ListPage** -- Which **contains List box** (all cities show here)

So when user clicks on button in the HomePage, then i'll navigate to ListPage to select city.
When user clicks on any city from the list, then i have to dismiss that ListPage and then immediately the selected city should update as button's content in the HomePage.

Please help me how to do the above task.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "MVVM Light" library then you can use Messenger service Like this....

in second page after selection is changed send a message

```
Messenger.Default.Send<type>(message,token);
```

and then in the consructor of page 1 viewmodel

```
Messenger.Default.Register<type>(this,token,Method);
```

here token should be same as sender token....

then

```
void Method(type message)
{
  button.content = message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way is to implement the PropertyChanged subscription.

```
//In your HomePage class
HomePage()
{
    ListPage.PropertyChanged +=this.CitySelected //Subscribe to the property changed event
}

void CitySelected(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "NewCity")
    {
        City selectedCity= (sender as ListPage).NewCity;
    }
}

//In your ListPage class
//You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

ListPage:INotifyPropertyChanged

private city newCity;
public City NewCity
{
get{return newCity;}
set{
    newCity=value;
    NotifyChange("NewCity");
}
}

void CitySelected(City selected)
{
    NewCity=selected;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public delegate void PropertyChangeHandler(object sender, EventArgs data);

protected void NotifyChange(string args)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(args));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you change your workflow to use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com) ListPicker control. This control matches the style you see in the Settings app of the phone. The ListPicker allows users to tap the selected item and be navigated to another page that offers them a list of available options. Here is an example

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="City"/>
    <toolkit:ListPicker ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
                        FullModeHeader="CITY"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}">
        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="0,20" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
</StackPanel>
```

Your DataContext would look something like

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
       Cities = new List<City> { new City("Denver"), new City("New York") };
    }

    public City SelectedCity 
    {
        { get return _city; }
        { _city = value; OnpropertyChanged("SelectedCity"); }
    }
    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna be very simple. What you have to do is, use NavigationService.Navigate(), and then append the selected city along with the HomePage page uri and in the HomePage page, retrieve the selected city using NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue() and assign the value in your button.

For ex,

In your ListPage.cs,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml?selectedCity=" + "Coimbatore", UriKind.Relative));
```

In your HomePage.cs,

```
string selectedCity = "";
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedCity", out selectedCity);
button.Content = selectedCity;
```

Thanks